# string localisation missing some special characters

Tags: c++, cocoa-touch, localization, xcode7.2

i'm working with localisation for c++ project & got references from "[this link](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com/2014/05/ios-localization-of-strings-in-c.html)"

in "LocalizationManager.mm" file it has method getLocalizedString as :

```
std::string LocalizationManager::getLocalizedString(const std::string& key)
{ 
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: key.c_str()];
std::string s([NSLocalizedString(str, nil) UTF8String]);
return s; 
}
```

and call it in .cpp files as :

```
std::string strHighscore = LocalizationManager::getInstance() -> getLocalizedString("best");
```

The problem here is that for some reasons , it didnt show localised strings for japanese or chinese language (i.e blank) and also some special characters when using vienamese are missing. Though other languages (like german) are supported fine ofcourse.

My guess is it has to do something with UTF8, but am too beginner for such. Anything pointing to what i'm doing wrong would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

i wasn't looking into the basic mistake i made. I had made custom font setup on localised string later which wasn't supporting some of unicodes including ja - zh - vi and others..

Apologies!

note:
i'm now using "simsun.ttc" font which seems to be supporting most of unicodes.